# Visual Studio Cordova, building iOS package via remote agent issues

Tags: ios, json, remote-server, visual-studio-cordova

We've been building a mobile application in Visual Studid Community 2015 using the Cordova platform with the aim to publish to Android and iOS.

Android we have no issues with but want to submit the app to Apple.  The problem is that we tried setting up a remote agent the last couple of days but have ran into a brick wall.

On our Macbook Pro we've installed node latest version as we are running Cordova CLI 5.4.1.  Also we've installed xCode latest version.  Signed up for Apple's developer program, created a distribution profile, got our certificate etc.  In other words we've ticked all the boxes.

Now the issue is once we try running the remote agent and trying to connect remotely via Visual Studio to our Mac to submit to the Apple store.  If we use remote agent we get the follwoing 404 error in Mac's terminal:

```
GET /certs/{pin number} 200 12ms - 3.49kb
GET /modules/taco-remote 404 3ms
```

And in Visual Studio the following pop up:

```
Unable to connect to remote iOS build server. Underlying exception:
The remote server returned an error: (404) not found.
```

If we try to use remotebuild we get an error "error parsing JSON remotebuild.config".

We've tried finding documentation or information on either of these but everything just points back to: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/ for remote build or Visual Studio's pages on how to install and run remote agent.

We've followed those steps 10 times but just keep on getting the same error.  If we try from another computer's Visual Studio we get an error "Could not resolve host" though the host name is definitely correct.

We are using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen the `GET /modules/taco-remote 404` error in the past, when trying to use an older vs-mda-remote NPM package for remote build. I'm assuming you're using the remotebuild package now, installed using `npm install -g remotebuild`. Is that correct?

Comment: Would you please post the contents of your `~/.taco_home/remotebuild.config` file?

Comment: I tried it on a different Mac and worked perfectly, thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, Ewan - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered issues with remote build and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com